# How to map this domain to a rectangle?

Tags: integration

Task:

Integrate, using a change of variables

$$\iint_R (xy)^2 \, dx \, dy $$

Where $R$ is the region bounded by the curves $xy=1,xy=2,y=3x,y=\frac x 2$.

I want to map $R$ to a rectangle or some easier domain, but all the substitutions I tried ended up on a more difficult domain, or they would keep having a hyperbola as a bound.

Which substitution could I use? How would I figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use this change of variables:

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
u = xy\\
v = \frac{y}{x}
\end{array} \right.$$

Comment: How did you figure out that would help?

Comment: Actually, if you look at the equations of your boundary, you see that this change of variables will turn them to the desired forms of being the sides of a rectangle! Also, experience ans solving similar problems lead me to suggest this! :) Do you want me to explain more in the answer? :)

Comment: satisfied with this? :)

Comment: Yes! thank you very much!!

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD:  Would you please check mark it? :)

Comment: Haha, sorry, thought I had done it, I'm kinda slow today.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to $ r,\theta$ from $ x,y$

$$d A=  dx \;dy = r \,d \theta\, dr,\; \frac {y}{x} = \tan \theta $$ and so on.

Comment: Are you sure about what you have written? :) It does not make sense! :)

Comment: $ {y\over x} = {\theta} $? Do you mean $ {y\over x} = {\arctan{\theta}} $?